# Extra 1px space between child and parent depending of the text's child

Tags: html, css

I have a container with width/height on `auto` and its child with width/height `100%`, i'm using `box-sizing: border-box;` on the child so that's not the solution.

As you can see on the screenshot below, there is an extra space (the white lines). It changes depending of the text inside the child.

https://jsfiddle.net/68uh1efq/

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45234850 That answer will solve your problem

Comment: thank you, `inline-table` did the trick....

Answer (score 1):

this is happening because of display property

try using this

```
.example {   
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  background-color:white;
  border:22px solid green;
  text-decoration:none;
    padding:20px 20px;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;

}

.example div { 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color:blue;
  border:none;
  /* padding:20px 20px; */
  padding:20;
  margin:0;
  color:#fff;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```